# Layering in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create an Android/Jetpack Compose layout that has a toolbar at the bottom and a normal layout screen.

But behind the toolbar and in front of the main screen, I'm trying to add a layer, that can be opened to fill the page, and then collapse, as shown in Fig1 to Fig2 and back.

The main sticking point I'm struggling with is the layering of three components on top of each other. What is the best way to layer component on top of each other in Jetpack Compose like this?

Fig1

[image: Fig1]

Fig2

[image: Fig2]

Comment: You can use a `Box` for this

Comment: the layout that is used to put items on top of each other is BOX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, Box was the way to go.

In case someone else is looking for a similar solution:

```
@Composable
fun Layout() {
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val size: Dp by animateDpAsState(if(expanded) screenHeight else 120.dp)

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.DarkGray)
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(size)
            .background(color = Color.Yellow)
            .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Text("History")

            Button(onClick = {
                expanded = !expanded
            }) {
                Text("^")
            }
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(60.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Green)
            .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
    ) {

    }
}
}
```